# Cron job seems to be running but no output and got killed after a while

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run my python scripts with crontab. I have 2 python scripts in the same directory. The first one `file1.py` has just 1 line `print(1)`. The second file `file2.py` begins with `print(2)` but then a long code to query and update data in my SQL database.

My setup in `crontab -e` is something like this (I set up the files to run every minute and save the output to `cron.log`

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/files && python3 file1.py >> /path/to/files/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * * cd /path/to/files && python3 file2.py >> /path/to/files/cron.log 2>&1
```

When I check the output in `cron.log`, at first I only see `1`, which is from `file1.py` but I don't see any `2`, the output of `file2.py`. However, after a while, maybe 10 minutes or so, I see `Killed` in `cron.log`.

I think the `Killed` message means cron started the job to run `file2.py` and killed the job after a while. I am not interested in the reason why cron kills my job. What I am confused is if cron started the job to run `file2.py`, why there is no `2` in `cron.log`. All I see is `1` and `Killed`. Both of these files run without any problem when I run them manually. Appreciate any help

Comment: sorry my bad, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because when the output is redirected, python3 buffers its standard output stream - and the buffer is not getting flushed when the process is killed.

To illustrate, given

```
$ cat file2.py
import time
print(2)
time.sleep(5)
```

then

```
$ timeout 3 python3 file2.py
2
```

whereas

```
$ timeout 3 python3 file2.py | cat
Terminated
```

If you force `python3` to unbuffer its streams you will likely see the expected log output:

```
$ timeout 3 python3 -u file2.py | cat
2
Terminated
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I need to unbuffer the output. Sorry this is my first time asking on this community so can't upvote your answer yet (not enough reputation).

Comment: Would it make sense to write the output to two separate cron.log files to alleviate contention?

Comment: @mondotofu that's a good question - I really don't know